# External HDD reallocate sector count [crystal disk]

Tags: external-hard-drive, smart, bad-sectors

I ran crystal disk to try and find out the problems with my EHDD and it's come up with a caution, does this report show that it's FUBAR?

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your disk is not FUBAR yet, but it is highly lightly to become FUBAR soon (Nobody knows how soon, just "soon"). Make sure you have up-to-date backups, and then either run the disk into the ground or preemptively replace it with a new disk and move this disk to holding less-critical data.

Comment: It's holing non-critical data at the moment, but it's also only allowing me to write 130GB out of 250GB, is this a common problem associated with reallocated sector counts?

Comment: No. Reallocated sectors are taken from a reserved pool of hidden sectors, so the disk's size should get smaller (until it runs out of those reserved sectors, at which point no more sectors will be reallocated, and you'll just have bad sectors that lose data). That sounds like a partitioning issue.

Comment: there are no partitions, it's showing that it is 250GB in size but when trying to fill it the most I can put on is 130GB, can't format either, I'm doing a zero byte write at the minuet. hopefully that will solve something

Comment: @DarthAndroid: "That sounds like a partitioning issue." - That's what I thought as well ([my comment](http://superuser.com/questions/609997/hdd-failure-to-write-past-a-certain-amount-and-unable-to-full-formant#comment754965_609997) on the OP's previous question should be visible to you). Looks like the drive's in pretty bad shape.

Comment: Also using a hex editor inspecting my HD, at around 27% everything is just FF FF FF over and over again, could that be the problem?

Comment: @user2341069: What was the result of zero filling the drive? Did that fail midway too?

Comment: It's currently on 20% I'll post an update in the morning

Comment: Yeah it stopped at 27%, thanks for the help anyway :)